# Xcode bundle identifier

Tags: xcode, bundle-identifier

Do I really have to put a company identifier into my app? (Like com.example)
When my app arrives to the app store will it be a link for a website?
I don't have a website, so do I have to create one?
Is there any way to not put the company identifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I think this is not like as you thinking about it.

A `bundle ID` precisely identifies a single app. A `bundle ID` is used during the development process to provision devices and by the operating system when the app is distributed to customers.So there is no need to add name of the company or etc.

The `bundle ID` string must be a `uniform type identifier (UTI)` that contains only alphanumeric characters (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.). The string should be in reverse-DNS format. For example, if your company’s domain is Ajax.com and you create an app named Hello, you could assign the string `com.Ajax.Hello` as your app’s bundle ID. For More you can review this document about by [AppDistributionGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html) `Apple`

And As when we submit the app it requires some links of website as i put `Apple.com` as i di't have website.

[image]

As the `Support` URL is for that provide support for the App that you submitting on App store and another one is for providing the information that you submitting on App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You should setup at least a basic web site for your customers, for support and so you can show a little more about your app than what the App Store allows. You can setup cheap (but decent) hosting at Squarespace.com or something similar.

I definitely wouldn't put Apple.com as your support URL. I've actually seen apps rejected because the web site they linked to for support wasn't available when they reviewed the app. That was a few years ago, not sure if they're still strict on that.

The idea for the bundle id is to ensure you pick something unique that won't conflict with others. If you use com.example.myapp, but don't actually have the example.com domain, it's possible you'll conflict with someone who does have example.com.